# How to deal with unwanted 180 rotation of x-axis in bar plot

Tags: r, plot

This figure, notice that the row x-axis (marked with 1%, etc)  is rotated.

[image]

Why is that happening with my code below. And how can I put it back to normal?

```
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1586262/plain/")
colnames(dat) <- c("Method", "Coverage",  "error 0%", "error 1%", "error 2%", "error 4%")

pdf(file="~/Desktop/Temp.pdf",height=7,width=10);

layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3),nrow=2,byrow = TRUE),heights=c(2,0.2))
par(omi=c(0,0.2,0.1,0.2))
barcols <- c("#636363","#bdbdbd")


lapply(unique(dat$Coverage),
        function(x){
            par(las=2);
            z<-as.matrix(dat[dat$Coverage==x,-(1:2)]);
            colnames(z)=NULL;
            rownames(z)=NULL;
            bp <- barplot(z,beside=TRUE,col=barcols,border=NA,ylim=c(0,1),xlab="Error rate")
            title(main=x,cex.main=1.75,font.main=1)
            xaxislab <- c("0%","1%","2%","4%") 
            axis(1,at=colMeans(bp),xaxislab,lwd=0,lwd.tick=1)
            abline(h=0)
          } 
)         

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
legend("topleft",c("Method1","Method2"),box.col="white",fill=barcols,cex=1.75,horiz=TRUE,border=NA)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have `par(las=2)` for "always perpendicular to the axis", but perhaps you want `las=1` for "always horizontal".